# Can't get ajax to work in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to run an ajax request in CakePHP 2.3. I am working off of this post:
[simple ajax example with cakephp 2.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768635/simple-ajax-example-with-cakephp-2-3-0)

I cant get it to work, here is my code:

```
$("#node-form-save").click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        var firstName = $("#node-form-first-name").val();
        var lastName = $("#node-form-last-name").val();
        var dob = $("#node-form-dob").val();
        $.ajax({
            url:'/persons/create',
            type: 'GET',
            datatype: 'json',
            data: {firstName: firstName, lastname: lastName, dob:dob},
            success: function(data){
                alert("succes");
                }
        });
        $('#modal-pop').jqmHide();

    })
```

I started with a simple test, to see if the sucess function is reached, but I get no alert. What is wrong with my code? The url is correct. The url /persons works, and when I type in /persons/create I get a CakePHP screen saying that I have no view (but I don't want one, I am doing ajax.
I list my controller (PersonsController.php) below

```
class PersonsController extends AppController
{
public $helpers = array('html', 'form');

public function index()
{

}

public function create()
{

}
}
```

I left the functions blank for now, just so I can get the basic functionality working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: **why "get"**?? Seems uber insecure for a create function. Do the ajax call by POST instead.

You said you don't want a view, but your code nowhere specifies that. For ajax, and to avoid rendering the view and the layout, do this

```
public function create() {
    $this->autoRender = false;
}
```

Also, if you do that, you won't get anything in return, so in the action, you need to echo the values so ajax can recieve it.

And a tip, you can separate the functions you want to excecute with ajax and the normal way with a simple check

```
public function create() {
    if( $this->request->is('ajax') ) {
        $this->autoRender = false;
        echo 'hello result';
        return;
    }

    //else, handle this action as a normal one and render a view and whatever
}
```

Comment: You wrote "so in the action, you need to echo the values so ajax can recieve it." What does this mean?

Comment: It means that if you don't render a view, then what result is the ajax going to get? Nothing. So you echo the result, something like `echo "[{id:1}]"` or a valid json. That way the success function of jquery can receive a result and parse it.

Comment: I just added $this -> autorender = false;
  echo "hello"; to my create() function and the alert still isn't happening. I even changed the alert to be alert(data); and still nothing. Any more ideas?

Comment: If it helps anything: I originally made the ajax and forgot to first make the create() function in the controller. At that time, the parameters showed up on the url (because is a GET... Yes, its only for testing.) But after I made the create(), now I don't see any parameters in the url when I click save.

Comment: Debug. Check with the fail option (`jqXHR.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {});`) of jquery ajax and see what is returning. If it's not returning anything there either, then I think you're probably hitting the wrong url. Also, if you are still testing with GET, then the params need to be inside create (`create($fName, $lName, $dob)`).

Comment: That my issue, I don't know how to debug an ajax call. When I step through the code and reach the ajax call, I don't know what to look for inside the jquery ajax call. What is jqXHR.fail and where can i find it?

Comment: Then you need to post that *that* is your issue first. Look at the [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), specifically for `fail` and `always` function, great way to debug. If your call hits those functions instead of `success`, then you are not making the call correctly, if you get a `500 error`, check for errors in the action.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that and if I still have an issue I'll repost.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the "event" to the function:

```
$("#node-form-save").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        ...
}
```

Comment: Didn't help. But I don't think you need to do that, I prevented the default action even without passing event in...

Answer (score 0):

this is how i have done this.hope it helps

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".submit").click(function(event){//my submit button has class name 'submit'
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"/cakephp/messages/create/",
            success : function(data) {
                alert('success');

            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
public function create(){
    if( $this->request->is('ajax') ) {
        $this->autoRender = false;
        echo 'hello result';
        return;
    }
  }
```