# Cakephp 3.6.14: Create and submit form with table and checkbox for each row (2nd form - same page)

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, checkbox, cakephp-3.x

I want to implement 2 different forms in a page for 2 different actions in the same controller. I am trying to create the second form where the user can check a checkbox for each row of a table. On submit of the form I want to execute some code in the `add` action of the controller.

This is my `AddElement\index.ctp` :

```
<div class="row"> //First form is working fine
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('AddElement', array('action' => 'index')); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->control('element_categories', ['options' => $elementCategories, 'empty' => true]); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->button(__('Filter'), ['class'=>'btn-success']); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
</div>

<h3><?= __('Task Elements') ?></h3>//2nd form not working as expected
<?php echo $this->Form->create('AddElement', array('action' => 'add')); ?>
<?php foreach ($taskElements as $taskElement): ?>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('id') ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('name') ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('element_category_id') ?></th>
            <th scope="col">Select</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $this->Number->format($taskElement->id) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($taskElement->name) ?></td>
            <td><?= $taskElement->element_category_id != 0 ? $this->Html->link($taskElement->element_category->name, ['controller' => 'ElementCategories', 'action' => 'view', $taskElement->element_category->id]) : '' ?></td>
            <td><?= $this->Form->control('selected', ['type' => 'checkbox']);?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>            
    </tbody>
</table><?php
echo $this->Form->button('Add');
echo $this->Form->end();?>
```

And this is the `add` action of the `AddElementController.php`:

```
public function add($tasktypeid)
{   
    $this->autoRender = false; //no need for view

    debug($this->request->data());
    if($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        debug($this->request->data());
    }

}
```

But when I click submit it does nothing. Its just loading for a second but it doesn't execute the code in the controller.

Comment: Step 1: Stop creating invalid HTML. You can not nest a form into a tbody like that - it either needs to go around the whole table element, or reside completely within a single table cell.

Comment: @misorude thx I corrected my question

Comment: In your case, I would use Ajax to submit your second form.

Comment: You are not closing the first form, `$this->end()` is for ending block capturing.

Comment: @ndm didn't help... thx anyway

Comment: @proprit can you give me more information?

Comment: With some javascript code, you prevent  the classic form submission for the second form, and then you submit the form with an ajax request to your second action. You  can use this question as an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095792/cant-get-ajax-to-work-in-cakephp .